# Xfce equivalent for advanced keyboard settings - e.g. for "Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level" or "Caps lock behavior"

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce, settings

I had a situation where I needed to disable right-Alt for selecting 3rd level and to set a new key for that level, as said [here](https://superuser.com/a/1703135/1039759). In KDE Plasma there are obvious settings under *System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced*,

[image]

while in Gnome they are under *Gnome-tweak-tool - Typing - Key to choose 3rd level - Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level.*

[image]

Are there such settings in Xfce?

Comment: `setxkbmap` and `lv3` option? see [this](https://gist.github.com/jatcwang/ae3b7019f219b8cdc6798329108c9aee)

Comment: @Andra - I was thinking about a GUI setting... I think a such tool is available in Mate. Maybe that could be installed in Xfce, but I am not sure and I don't remember how it's called.

Comment: mate-control-center -> mate-keyboard-properties